# Firestore Rules: Can we access a parent's document wildcare in children rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Let the following rules:

```
match /users/{user} {  // Do not specify any authentication for the read rule - Do not specify any delete rule
  allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && resource.data.login == "Anonymous" && resource.data.avatar_is_defined == false && resource.data.show_in_amounts_ranking == false && resource.data.amount == 0.0 && resource.data.deleted == false;
  allow update: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == user && resource.data.deleted != true;
  allow read: if resource.data.deleted != true;

  match /seals/{seal} {  // Do not specify any delete rule
    allow create: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == user && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(user)).data.deleted != true && resource.data.title != "";
    allow update: if request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.uid == user && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(user)).data.deleted != true && ((resource.data.title != "" && request.resource.data.amount > resource.data.amount) || (resource.data.title == "" && request.resource.data.amount == resource.data.amount));
    allow read: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(user)).data.deleted != true;
```

Is it correct to use `$(user)` in the `read` rule of `match /seals/{seal}`, even if the wildcard `{user}` is defined **in the parent** `match /users/{user}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use wildcards from any outer match that's in scope, going all the way up to the top `service` scope.  It works just like you would expect with most programming languages that have nested variable scope.  Notice how $(database) also works fine, which was matched at a higher level.

Comment: Thanks again Doug, as usual! Could you btw confirm that there is an "exception": the access to a parent document's **field** can't be done just using `resource.data`, but requires `get` (I have read that in a SO question's accepted answer)?

Comment: This sounds like a different question than the one you started out with - please post it separately and explain fully what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi Doug, I won't open another question because the one I asked already exists on StackOverflow, I rather wanted a quick confirmation in 2 or 3 words:) But thank you very much anyway!